# Gostaria de saber como receber o valor do meu select ao clicar em um option com javascript puro?

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso receber esses valores sem que haja um botão, somente clicando no campo. O `select` possui mais de 50 `option` vindos de um laço PHP.

```html
<select>
  <option value="campo1">campo1</option>
  <option value="campo2">campo2</option>
  <option value="campo3">campo3</option>
...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta escutar o o evento `change` no select e determinar o seu valor.
Podes a qualquer momento saber o valor usando:

```
const select = document.querySelector('select');
console.log('O valor do select é ', select.value);
```

Para saber quando o valor muda podes usar assim:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const selectValue = this.value;
  alert(selectValue); // este é o valor que procuras
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="campo1">campo1</option>
  <option value="campo2">campo2</option>
  <option value="campo3">campo3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o evento onchange do Javascript. Assim, toda vez que uma mudança ocorrer no select, a função `alteraValor` será chamada, e nesse caso irá imprimir no console o valor recuperado.

```js
function alteraValor() {
  var selectElement = document.getElementById("select")
  var valorSelecionado = selectElement.value
  console.log(valorSelecionado)
 }
```

```html
<select id="select" onchange="alteraValor()">
    <option value="campo1">campo1</option>
    <option value="campo2">campo2</option>
    <option value="campo3">campo3</option>
</select>
```